# Gcloud compute mount ssd

Tags: linux, wordpress, lamp, gcloud

I am running Wordpress on GCloud Compute.  I am fine with Wordpress but Linux is beyond me!

I have tried to add a new SSD disk in GCloud Compute to speed up server response time, following these instructions https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/local-ssd.  The first part works fine and I can see the disk sitting there in Gcloud (screenshot1):

www[dot]financialtrainingassociates[dot]com/images/screenshot1.JPG

But then in my SSH terminal I follow the instructions (step #4 under "Format and mount..." in the instructions) and run this command:

```
ls /dev/disk/by-id/
```

But **I can't see the new SSD disk listed** (screenshot2):

www[dot]financialtrainingassociates[dot]com/images/screenshot2.JPG

```
google-disk-1        google-fta-boot-disk        scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_disk-1        scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_fta-boot-disk
google-disk-1-part1  google-fta-boot-disk-part1  scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_disk-1-part1  scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_fta-boot-disk-part1
```

What command do I need to run to get the new SSD showing in the list above?

Thanks a lot for your patience - I am brand new to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Could you describe how you created the instance?

I ran the following command:

```
$ gcloud compute instances create example-instance --local-ssd \  
  interface=NVME --image-family ubuntu-1610 --zone us-central1-a \ 
  --image-project ubuntu-os-cloud
```

and when I ssh'd to the instance using:

```
gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone us-central1-a
```

I could see the SSD right away:

```
$ ls /dev/disk/by-id/
google-persistent-disk-0         google-persistent-disk-0-part15                                    scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0         scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0-part15
google-persistent-disk-0-part1   nvme-nvme.1ae0-6e766d655f6361726400-6e766d655f6361726400-00000001  scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0-part1
google-persistent-disk-0-part14  nvme-nvme_card_nvme_card                                           scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-0-part14
```

Comment: Thanks you are right - I was missing it the whole time.  Thank you!